# Setting up Samba to use AD server for authentication?

Tags: samba, authentication, active-directory

I am looking for howtos or instructions on setting up Samba to use an AD server for authentication instead of using a Samba password file.  Pointers to documentation helpful, especially the right document to look at on http://samba.org/samba/docs/ .

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want Samba to join to a Windows Server running Active Directory as a [Domain Member](http://samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/domain-member.html)  You will need to set-up Winbind as well using either pam_smb or pam_winbind. I can't remember exactly.  Lastly, you will need the winbind nss module activated in /etc/nsswitch.conf for passwd/groups.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Active_Directory_Integration) is a good guide for ArchLinux. It worked quite well for me and may be feasible for other distributions, too.